# JavaScript RegEx: replace text in string between two "markers"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

*I need this:*

Input

```
<div>some text [img]path_to_image.jpg[\img]</div>
<div>some more text</div>
<div> and some more and more text [img]path_to_image2.jpg[\img]</div>
```

Output

```
<div>some text <img src="path_to_image.jpg"></div>
<div>some more text</div>
<div>and some more and more text <img src="path_to_image2.jpg"></div>
```

*This is my try and also fail*

```
var input  = "some text [img]path_to_image[/img] some other text";
var output = input.replace (/(?:(?:\[img\]|\[\/img\])*)/mg, "");
alert(output)
//output: some text path_to_image some other text
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regex, just do:

```
var output = input.replace ("[img]","<img src=\"").replace("[/img]","\">");
```

Answer (score 6):

A regexp like

```
var output = input.replace (/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/g, "<img src='$1'/>");
```

should do

The ouptut of your test is then `some text <img src='path_to_image'/> some other text`

Answer (score 1):

Your input example terminates with `[\img]` not `[/img]` as your RE searches for.

```
var input  = '<div>some text [img]path_to_image.jpg[\img]</div>\r\n'
    input += '<div>some more text</div>\r\n'
    input += '<div> and some more and more text [img]path_to_image2.jpg[\img]</div>'

var output = input.replace(/(\[img\](.*)\[\\img\])/igm, "<img src=\"$2\">");
alert(output)
```

:

```
<div>some text <img src="path_to_image.jpg"></div>
<div>some more text</div>
<div> and some more and more text <img src="path_to_image2.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
var _str = "replace 'something' between two markers" ;
// Let both left and right markers be the quote char.
// This reg expr splits the query string into three atoms
// which will be re-arranged as desired into the input string
document.write( "INPUT : " + _str + "<br>" );
_str = _str.replace( /(\')(.*?)(\')/gi, "($1)*some string*($3)" );
document.write( "OUTPUT : " + _str + "<br>" );
```